# Axios call in redux-toolkit middleware gone into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, middleware, redux-toolkit

I have `redux-toolkit` for state management in my react project and I am using one Middleware function for doing change in the payload before sending to the reducer. In the middleware file, I am doing one Api call for changing text into ES but because of error into my Api this middleware function goes into the infinite loop. You can see the middleware function and Api call code in below snippet.

```js
import { getSpanishText } from "../../helpers/storeSpanishText";

export const kioskSettingsMiddleware = (store) => (next) => async (action) => {
    const actionType = action.type;
    if (actionType === "kisokSettings/saveKioskPortalSettings") {
      const prevState = store.getState().kioskSettings;
      const data = action.payload;
      let settingObject = {
        autoDisconnect: data.auto_hang_up_call,
        multiPMS: data?.is_multi_pms_mapping,
      };

    if (
      data?.is_complete_operation_message &&
      data?.complete_operation_message !== prevState?.completeMessage
    ) {
      settingObject["completeMessage"] = data?.complete_operation_message;
      settingObject["EScompleteMessage"] = await getSpanishText(
        "EScompleteMessage",
        data?.complete_operation_message
      );
    }
   
    return store.dispatch({ type: actionType, payload: settingObject });
  }
  return next(action);
}
```

Here is the API call code

```js
export const getSpanishText = (key, msg) => {
  return axios
    .get(`https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2`, {
      params: {
        key: TRANSLATE_API_KEY,
        q: msg,
        target: "es",
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        ipcRenderer.send("logs", {
          type: "info",
          msg: `ES TRANSLATION- [${key} : ${res.data.data.translations[0].translatedText}]`,
        });
        return res.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      ipcRenderer.send("logs", {
        type: "info",
        msg: `FALLBACK EN - [${key} : ${msg}]`,
      });
      return msg;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
    return store.dispatch({ type: actionType, payload: settingObject });
```

starts a new dispatch with the same action type - so it will run into the same middleware again.

Maybe you wanted to call

```js
return next({ type: actionType, payload: settingObject })
```

instead?